# Does the RDS Snapshot System have a retention period?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[image]

I would like to know if the RDS Snapshot System has backup retention and where can I check the retention period for these system backups?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Automated snapshots** are retained for a period you select when launching the database, up to 35 days.

**Manual snapshots** (created via the Amazon RDS management console, AWS CLI or AWS SDK) are retained *forever* until you delete them.

Comment: and the Automated backup is the same that snapshot system?

Comment: The automated system creates snapshots on a schedule. The snapshots are the same as the manually-created snapshots.

Comment: @AnonimaOs Automated backups are 0 to 35 days. If you don't set the backup retention period, the default backup retention period is **one day** if you create the database using the Amazon RDS API or the AWS CLI. The default backup retention period is **seven days** if you create the database using the console.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set RDS backup retention period to between 0 and 35 days. Setting the backup retention period to 0 disables automated backups.

> Backup retention period. You can set the backup retention period when you create a DB instance. If you don't set the backup retention period, the default backup retention period is one day if you create the DB instance using the Amazon RDS API or the AWS CLI. The default backup retention period is seven days if you create the DB instance using the console

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html

Answer (score 1):

very confusing, backup is different way of  storing data
so it's not clear if "backup retention period" is also snapshot retention period
even if it is aws doc doesn't mention anything about System Snapshots